# How can I make columns in an Excel spreadsheet sortable while maintaining row integrity?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I notice on an existing spreadsheet that I can sort by the various columns, but only the order of contents of that column change; I want the other columns to change, too, when one column is sorted.

In fact, I have a hard time understanding why anybody would NOT want the row values to maintain their integrity by each row remaining the same when any column in that row is sorted.

IOW, in this simple group of information:

```
FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME
Bruce                Springsteen
Woody                Guthrie
Stephen              Foster
Bob                  Dylan
```

…when I sort by FirstName A-Z, I want  it to be this:

```
FIRSTNAME          LASTNAME
Bob                Dylan
Bruce              Springsteen
Stephen            Foster
Woody              Guthrie
```

…not  this:

```
FIRSTNAME        LASTNAME
Bob                Springsteen
Bruce              Guthrie
Stephen            Foster
Woody              Dylan
```

Comment: Do you have a blank column between the two columns shown?

Comment: select the entire span of columns where you want to maintain the row integrity. there are various scenarios in which this integrity is not maintained (by design and this not a flaw). e.g. when you are dealing with more than one excel tables, they can be sorted independent of each other, blank columns in between (as noted by Mark), etc. When you select a single column and try to sort, Excel does warn you (Sort Warning) when you try to sort by selecting just a single column and prompts you to either "Expand the selection" or "Continue with the current selection"

Comment: @BharatAnand: I was sorting yesterday on an Excel spreadsheet that somebody else created, and it was not giving me any warning about the goofiness of the behavior (sorting one column only, while leaving all the others static).

Comment: @Mark: No, there are no blank columns

Comment: Make sure when you hit the Filter button that you get the little triangles for every column, as opposed to just some of them. Also check that your cell format type is consistent down the length of each column you intend to sort.

Comment: We will probably need to see a screenshot to comment further on this issue

Comment: @BharatAnand: No can do, I would be violating HIIPA (sp?) to do so.

Comment: what is HIIPA.. and  sp.. ?

Comment: @p._phidot_: "sp?" is "spelling?" (meaning the writer is unsure of the spelling). Perhaps I should have written "acronym?" HIIPA or HIPA or HIPPA or whatever it is is the law protecting patients' privacy.

Comment: thanks.. It's [HIPAA](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/security/laws-regulations/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you data located in column A & B , where Row 1 is the label, and Row 2 is the 1st data.

1. Select both column.
2. Data > Filter .
3. Then click on the small triangle
   @ A1.

Done.

Hope it helps.